# Limsup of independent exponential random variables

Tags: probability-theory

In the lecture, we are given an example on independent and identically distributed random variables, but I am not quite sure what is the idea of this question. The exercise is as following:

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Assume that $X_1$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda > 0$. The distribution of $X_1$ is absolutely continuous with density function $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Show that $\mathbb{P}(\lim\sup_{n\to \infty}X_n/\log(n)=1/\lambda)=1$.

I know that for the exponential distribution, the mean $\mathbb{E}[x]=1/\lambda$, it says $X_1$ is exponentially distributed, is that mean all of the $X_n$ are also exponentially distributed? $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}(X_n)$ means that $X_n$ happens for infinitely often times as $n$ close to infinity. so $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}(X_n)=\bigcap_{n∈N}\bigcup_{m>n}X_n$, and also as $n\to\infty$, $\log(n)\to\infty$ . I am not sure about what this question is asking about? Is it something with $0/1$ law? like if an event $A$ happens infinitely times, then $\mathbb{P}(A)\in\{0,1\}$

Can any one please help me with this question? details are preferred. Thanks!

Comment: please use Latex

Comment: I am not sure how to use Latex in here, sorry

Comment: @xz330 I have submitted a revision to your question that fixes the latex formatting. Please check that I haven't altered the meaning of your question.

Comment: @senshin thanks! any idea about this question?

Comment: Changed the title to something more accurate. Do you understand why it fits better the content of the question?

Answer (score 4):

> Show that $P(lim(n→∞)supXn/logn=1/λ)=1$.
>
> (...) $lim(n→∞)(supXn)$ means that Xn happens for infinitely often times as n close to infinity. so $lim(n→∞)(supXn)=⋂_n⋃_mXn$, where m>n and n∈N.

**This is confusing limsup of events and limsup of random variables.** Here, each $X_n$ is a random variable hence $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n/\log n$$ is the random variable $Y$ such that, for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$,
$$
Y(\omega)=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)/\log n.
$$
And the task is to prove that the event $[Y=1/\lambda]$ has probability $1$.

Note that the question most probably does not reproduce faithfully the text of the exercise asked. For example,
$$
\text{lim(n→∞)supXn/logn}
$$
should read
$$
\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n/\log n,
$$
where $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}$ acts as a single operation, or, equivalently,
$$
\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{\log n}.
$$

Comment: oh right, I got what it means now, but how do you prove that $P[Y=1/λ]=1$?

Comment: Yeah, I have changed all the equations to the proper formatting now.

Comment: That is a different question.

Comment: isn't it what the question is asking about?

Comment: No it is not. And if you want an answer to *that* other question, you should add your thoughts on it.

Comment: "I have changed all the equations to the proper formatting now." You have not, have you?

Comment: I have now! sorry. I have added all I know in the question and now I know what the question is asking about, but just don't know how to generate the process. I have searched that what $limsup_{n→∞}X_n$ means and put the result in the question.

Comment: Which similar questions can you solve?

Comment: I know that $P(limsup_{n→∞}X_n)=1$ if the summation of X_n is infinity

Comment: could u give me any hintplease?

Comment: "P(limsupn→∞Xn)=1 if the summation of X_n is infinity" Sorry but this is absurd on at least two counts. What does the string of characters "P(limsupn→∞Xn)" even mean?

Comment: this means Xn happens infinitely open, then that is equal to 1

Comment: Only, Xn does not "happen" since Xn is a *random variable*, not an event. Oh wait... isn't this exactly what my answer says? Did you even READ it or what? (Adding boldface to my answer, although I hate to do so.)

Comment: Can you please answer this question? this website said "we prefer answers rather than discussion"

Comment: I did answer the question. As already explained in a comment. But you do not read comments either?

Comment: which comment? none of ur comment gave me the answer to this question.

Comment: "If you want an answer to that other question, you should add your thoughts on it" (bis).